# Excel COUNTIF near cell have some value

Tags: excel, countif

I have problem with getting count of some value who in near cell have some name. I'm trying this:`=COUNTIF(C3:C20;B3:B20="apple")` But it returns 0. table like this:

```
apple     50
bannana   70
lemon     35
apple     45
lemon     25
```

I want to get sum of all apples, this time it be 95.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Sumif or Sumifs` instead. Like this:

```
=SUMIFS(C3:C20,B3:B20,"apple")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this one:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B3:B20="apple")*(C3:C20))
```

Comment: I know this, but I want to get sum of integer values near apple cell (50+45), on new cell function should get 95.